# XSLT Saxon - Getting Latest node value

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am trying to find the last element in my input xml, which looks like

```
<ROOT>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <FieldTag>AMOUNT</FieldTag>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <FieldTag>CAT_TYPE</FieldTag>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <FieldTag>NUMBER</FieldTag>
        </Item>
    </Items>
    <getResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <MAIN>
            <ArrayItem>
                <NUMBER>123456789</NUMBER>
                <CTRY>GB</CTRY>
                <NAME>TEST NAME</NAME>
                <RS>
                    <ArrayOfRSItem>
                        <DATE_1>2014-12-12T10:14:02-05:00</DATE_1>
                        <DATE_2>2014-12-12T10:13:53-05:00</DATE_2>
                        <AMOUNT>11111</AMOUNT>
                    </ArrayOfRSItem>
                    <ArrayOfRSItem>
                        <DATE_1>2014-12-13T17:16:19-05:00</DATE_1>
                        <DATE_2>2014-12-13T16:33:07-05:00</DATE_2>
                        <AMOUNT>22222</AMOUNT>
                    </ArrayOfRSItem>
                    <ArrayOfRSItem>
                        <DATE_1>2014-12-12T10:14:02-05:00</DATE_1>
                        <DATE_2>2014-12-12T10:13:53-05:00</DATE_2>
                        <CAT_TYPE>10000</CAT_TYPE>
                    </ArrayOfRSItem>
                    <ArrayOfRSItem>
                        <DATE_1>2014-12-13T17:16:19-05:00</DATE_1>
                        <DATE_2>2014-12-13T16:33:07-05:00</DATE_2>
                        <CAT_TYPE>20000</CAT_TYPE>
                    </ArrayOfRSItem>
                </RS>
            </ArrayItem>
        </MAIN>
    </getResponse>
</ROOT>
```

and I use following XSLT file for transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:urn="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02"
    xmlns:func="http://www.test.com/" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="urn func" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon">

    <xsl:output method ="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:if test="count(/ROOT/getResponse/MAIN/ArrayItem) &gt; 0" >
            <Data>
                <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/getResponse/MAIN/ArrayItem" >
                    <xsl:element name="NodeItem">
                        <xsl:variable name="TempNo" select="NUMBER"/>
                        <xsl:element name="Number">
                            <xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Country">
                            <xsl:value-of select="CTRY"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="DataChanges">
                            <xsl:for-each select="./RS/ArrayOfRSItem/*" >
                                <xsl:if test="name()!='DATE_1' and name()!='DATE_2' ">
                                <xsl:variable name="ChangedNodeName" select="name()"></xsl:variable>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/Items/Item">                                       
                                        <xsl:variable name="DisplayNodeName" select="FieldTag"></xsl:variable>
                                        <xsl:if test="$DisplayNodeName = $ChangedNodeName">
                                            <xsl:element name="FieldItem">
                                                <xsl:attribute name="Tag">
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="FieldTag"/>    
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                                <xsl:variable name="NodeFullText" select="concat('../../getResponse/MAIN/ArrayItem[NUMBER=',$TempNo,']/RS/ArrayOfRSItem/',$DisplayNodeName)"/>
                                                <xsl:attribute name="Value">
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="saxon:evaluate($NodeFullText)"/>
                                                </xsl:attribute>
                                             </xsl:element>

                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:if>
                               </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>                    
                </xsl:for-each>  
            </Data>
         </xsl:if>  
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get the desired output in the form of

```
<Data>
   <NodeItem>
      <Number>123456789</Number>
      <Country>GB</Country>
      <Name>TEST NAME</Name>
      <DataChanges>
        <FieldItem Tag="AMOUNT" Value="22222"/>
         <FieldItem Tag="CAT_TYPE" Value="20000"/>
      </DataChanges>
   </NodeItem>
</Data>
```

But I am getting the output xml as

```
<Data>
   <NodeItem>
      <Number>123456789</Number>
      <Country>GB</Country>
      <Name>TEST NAME</Name>
      <DataChanges>
         <FieldItem Tag="AMOUNT" Value="11111 22222"/>
         <FieldItem Tag="AMOUNT" Value="11111 22222"/>
         <FieldItem Tag="CAT_TYPE" Value="10000 20000"/>
         <FieldItem Tag="CAT_TYPE" Value="10000 20000"/>
      </DataChanges>
   </NodeItem>
</Data>
```

I need to get the latest AMOUNT entry and CAT_TYPE. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I need to get the latest AMOUNT entry and CAT_TYPE.*"   What exactly does "latest" mean here? Is it *last* (in document order) or *latest* (chronologically)? If the latter, by which of the two dates?

Comment: And a suggestion, XSLT needn't be that verbose as you've made. `<xsl:element name="NodeItem">..</xsl:element>` can be written as `<NodeItem>..</NodeItem>`. And attributes also can be put inside the element tags..

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this before. Based on the latest date1 field, I need the latest AMOUNT and CAT_TYPE.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Lingamurthy.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't this be (much) simpler?

**XSLT 1.0 (or 2.0)**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Data>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ROOT/getResponse/MAIN/ArrayItem"/>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ArrayItem">
    <NodeItem>
        <Number><xsl:value-of select="NUMBER"/></Number>
        <Country><xsl:value-of select="CTRY"/></Country>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></Name>
        <DataChanges>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="RS/ArrayOfRSItem/AMOUNT">
                <xsl:sort select="../DATE_1" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="RS/ArrayOfRSItem/CAT_TYPE">
                <xsl:sort select="../DATE_1" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </DataChanges>
   </NodeItem>
</xsl:template>         

<xsl:template match="AMOUNT | CAT_TYPE">    
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
        <FieldItem Tag="{local-name()}" Value="{.}"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**, when applied to your example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
   <NodeItem>
      <Number>123456789</Number>
      <Country>GB</Country>
      <Name>TEST NAME</Name>
      <DataChanges>
         <FieldItem Tag="AMOUNT" Value="22222"/>
         <FieldItem Tag="CAT_TYPE" Value="20000"/>
      </DataChanges>
   </NodeItem>
</Data>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It works. But it would be great if it could be solved with my XSLT.

Comment: It would be great if I could take the time to decipher it (which is by no means guaranteed to succeed). And even then I would suggest what I believe is the best method to arrive from input to output.

Comment: @user2864929 There is no reason to stick with complicated and long-winded code if there is a simple alternative solution that does the same.